# GCC linking wrong libpthread for build.rs

Tags: rust, pthreads, cross-platform, cross-compiling, nix

I'm attempting to cross-compile from Linux (NixOS) to Windows and encountering some frustrations.

There seem to be two parts that together are breaking the build:

- Code in my Rust project requires multithreading, and as such requires a version of `libpthread` for Windows.
- To build properly, I need a `build.rs` file. For some reason, Rust requires a version of `libpthread` for Linux for that.

What's the problem? Well, the `build.rs` has to be built with regular GCC and not MinGW because it needs to execute on my system. But for some reason, GCC is attempting to link to the Windows `libpthread` library instead of the system one, and as such is failing with an error about not supporting the library format.

### (Failed) Alternatives

If I remove the `build.rs`, the project builds fine. Unfortunately, I need it for full functionality.

If I remove the Windows version of `libpthread` the `build.rs` builds and runs correctly, but MinGW fails with a missing library error when building the rest of the project.

### Solution Paths?

Either I have to figure out why GCC's linking to the wrong version of `libpthread`, or I have to disable `-lpthread` entirely for the `build.rs`. I have no idea why it would need pthreads, considering for testing I stripped it down to only `fn main() {}`.

I have no idea where to start on either of these, and I've already spent a couple of days getting the problem down to this. I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: Might be useful to include the exact error message.

Comment: and how you wrote the expression.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I opened an issue in the Nixpkgs GitHub (https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/139966) so not sure what to do with this SO question now. I guess potential temporary solutions might be nice? Ideally I would fix the issue but I don't know what would have to happen.